# hide and filter record in crystal report

Tags: c#, sql, crystal-reports, report

in my report i have a Total  field and i cant use filter in my report , so i need hide other record.
 i have a date record when i want to hide other record in section expert/details/suppress use this formula `{Chc.CheckDate} in {?az} to {?ta}`
crystal report hide date between in `az` to `ta` and show me all Others date 
but i want show record in date between `az` to `ta`

for example i set `az: 2017/06/06` to `ta: 2017/06/08` show me all time From 2017/06/01 to 2017/06/20 except 2017/06/06 to 2017/06/08

how to show date between parameter az  to parameter ta?

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear but it sounds like you are using the Suppress expression for a section. In that case, simply change your expression to:

```
NOT ({Chc.CheckDate} in {?az} to {?ta})
```